# How to send Facebook Test Lead to Webhook - but from Test User's Test Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-test-users

As i'm testing leads retrieval and integration - i'm wondering did anybody found solution on how to

- create leadgen ad on *test page* of test user account
- create lead from test ad

So far i created leadgen_form on Test page via Graph API and test lead via Graph API. Lead is visible in "Publishing Tool -> Lead Ads Form -> Form Libray" but is not sent to webhook on creating.
(Despite my app being visible in "Leads Setup" and Webhook is working when testing it from developers.facebok.com)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to do this?